# How to get file from resource folder as File?

Tags: java, file, resources

I want to get a file from resources folder if it exists and create it there if it doesn't. I want to access it as file. class.getResource() doesn't work as it returns an URL. class.getResourceAsStream() gives input stream, but then I can't write in it or can I somehow?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Statistika {
File file;

public Statistika() {
    try {
        file = Statistika.class.getResourceAsStream("statistics.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        file = new File("statistics.txt");

    }
}
```

How to make this work?

Comment: What kind of application is? An applet, desktop, j2ee?

Comment: "and create it there if it doesn't." <-- and where? What if your classpath contains several URLs? How do you determine where to create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
File f = new File(Statistika.class.getResource("resource.name").toURI());
if (!f.isFile()){
    f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    f.createNewFile();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Statistika.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filename);`
If it returns null then you can create new file/directory. 
If your accessing this from jar then use `Statistika.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);`
Hope it will solve your problem. Let me know if you found any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `file = new File("statistics.txt");` in your catch block .. just do the following

```
try {
    File file = new File("statistics.txt");
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    fis = Statistika.class.getResourceAsStream(file.getName());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {


}
```

This is independent of whether the file exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File("statistics.txt");
try {
        f.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException ex) { }

InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
```

Use BufferedReader to insert contents to file referenced by f.